# Sed insert back reference into command

Tags: sed

Can i use matched group from sed command, for another command, which generates replacement. Something like that:

```
sed -e 's/\(<regex>\)/$(<command using \1 reference and generating replacement>)/g'
```

I need it for replacement in first file, according to another file contents (replacement not constant and based on concrete replaced line).

Comment: Not possible with traditional sed. In single quotes the `$()` command doesn't execute and sed places the back-reference into the literal `$(...)` string. In double quotes the `$()` command is execute *before* sed is even started so the `\1` is seen by the command as a literal string. Recent versions of GNU sed might be able to do this with the `e` modifier flag [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt).

Answer (score 2):

As @EtanReisner mentions, this is possible only with GNU sed -- and still somewhat tricky. Also, it is **potentially dangerous,** and you should only use it if the input comes from a trustworthy source.

Anyway, the `e` modifier to the `s///` command treats the contents of the pattern space after the substitution was made as a shell command, runs it, and replaces the pattern space with the output of that command, which means that the output will have to be shunted into place manually. A general pattern for this is

```
sed '/regex/ { h; s//\n/; x; s//\n&\n/; s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/command \1/e; x; G; s/\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/ }' filename
```

Let's go through this from the top:

```
/regex/ {                                  # When we find what we seek:

  h                                        # Make a copy of the current line in
                                           # the hold buffer.

  s//\n/                                   # Put a newline where the match occurs
                                           # (// reattempts the last attempted
                                           # regex, which is the one from the
                                           # start). This serves as a marker
                                           # where the output of the command will
                                           # be inserted.

  x                                        # Swap the copy back in; the marked
                                           # line moves to the hold buffer

  s//\n&\n/                                # put markers around the match this
                                           # time,

  s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/command \1/e            # then use those markers to construct
                                           # the command and run it. The pattern
                                           # space contains the output of the
                                           # command now.

  x                                        # swap the marked line back in

  G                                        # append the output to it

  s/\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/ # split, reassemble all that in
                                           # the right order, using the
                                           # newline marker we put there in
                                           # the beginning as a splitting
                                           # point.
}
```

`regex` and `command` have to be replaced with your regex and command, obviously. You can try this out with

```
echo 'foo /tmp/ bar' | sed '/\/\S*/ { h; s//\n/; x; s//\n&\n/; s/.*\n\(.*\)\n.*/ls \1/e; x; G; s/\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\(.*\)/\1\3\2/ }'
```

This will run `ls /tmp/` and put the listing between `foo` and `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it simpler and clearer to use awk. e.g. to multiply some number in the middle of the input by 3:

```
$ echo 'abc 12 def' |
    awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+/) {print substr($0,1,RSTART-1) substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)*3 substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}'
abc 36 def
```

With GNU awk you can use the 3rd arg to match() to save the regexp matching segments:

```
$ echo 'abc 12 def' |
    awk 'match($0,/(.* )([0-9]+)( .*)/,a){print a[1] a[2]*3 a[3]}'
abc 36 def
```

or to pass it to a shell command (probably not a good idea, but can be done):

```
$ echo 'abc 12 def' |
    awk 'match($0,/(.* )([0-9]+)( .*)/,a){system("echo \"" a[2] "\"")}'
12
```